# Laravel model factory make() bypass create() in foreign key object creation

Tags: laravel, unit-testing

I have a factory for Customer class

```
$factory->define(Customer::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'hotel_id' => function() {
            return factory(\App\Hotel::class)->create()->id;
        },
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'email' => $faker->email,
    ];
});
```

It's working fine for calling factory(Customer:class)->create().
However, if I want to factory(Customer:class)->make() to create Customer object in memory to pass to unit tests, this factory will create a Hotel object and persist to my database.

Is there a pattern that helps Laravel to recognize factory make(), and use a different approach when generating objects. Like when I call factory(Customer:class)->make(), it will generate

```
'name' => $faker->name,
'phone' => $faker->phoneNumber,
'email' => $faker->email,
```

THEN it will create a $hotel = factory(Hotel:class)->make() and do $customer->setRelation('hotel', $hotel) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the `hotel_id` out of the factory `define` and use the after callbacks instead.

From the documentation (my emphasis):

> Factory callbacks are registered using the afterMaking and
>   afterCreating methods, and allow you to perform additional tasks after
>   making or creating a model. For example, **you may use callbacks to
>   relate additional models to the created model**:

#### Example

```php
$factory->afterMaking(App\User::class, function ($user, $faker) {
    // ...
});

$factory->afterCreating(App\User::class, function ($user, $faker) {
    $user->accounts()->save(factory(App\Account::class)->make());
});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/database-testing#factory-callbacks

Comment: I've tried it out. Another problem pops up. Since my field is not nullable(), when I want to insert the object into DB, it's throwing SQL violation ( Since we plan to add the hotel_id after creation ). What's your solution ?

Comment: You could have hotel_id=0 in the factory define

Comment: .. as it will just be overridden by the after callbacks later anyway.

Comment: But it's a foreign key

Comment: In your original question you wrote that you want to create the Customer::class in memory to pass it to unit tests. In that case you don't need to fill hotel_id. You should assign a hotel before persisting it. So between creating the object in memory and persisting, create() a Hotel and attach that.

Comment: Yes, now factory(Customer)->make() is fine. But when I need to factory(Customer)->create(), I will have to  : factory(Customer)->make() , factory(Hotel)->create(), attach hotel to customer, save() , correct ? That's not what I ultimately needed

Comment: not  factory(Hotel)->make(), but  factory(Hotel)->create(). You will have to persist/save Hotel before saving Customer.

Comment: So long story short, now I can factory->make(), but factory->create() doesn't work any more since Laravel doesnt allow insert null into not nullable foreign key field

Comment: Correct, you could however call create() with overridden parameters, e.g.: $user = factory(Customer::class)->create([
    'hotel_id' =>  ....,
]);
and have the hotel_id in there. But raw create() won't work because the factory doesn't know what hotel id to attach, and your database structure doesn't allow empty hotel ids.

Comment: In the end, I have to Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints(); in define(), then enable it in afterCreating :( , ugly but works

Comment: Yeah I agree, that doesn't really sound like a pretty solution. And you are not able to restrain from using create() without defining hotel_id in overriding parameters?

Comment: Even if I throw in hotel_id in overriding parameters, MySql will still throw exception if I dont turn off the constraint.. so ya .. that's the best I can come up with